# Prevent dropped element from dropping into an already dropped element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

Thats a mouthful. But, heres the issue. I have elements that I can drag and drop into a large div. These elements clone from the original. It all works fine except for when the user accidentally drops a dragged element into an already dropped element. I know this will happen eventually and the outcome is a mess. Iv been looking for a solution for this and can't seem to find one.

Simply put, need a solution that prevents dropped elements from being dropped in already dropped elements. And if this is done, the dragged div simply moves to the bottom of the target div. Im sure there is a simple solution to this. I can't be the only one who has has this issue and if this has already been answered... shame on me.

Here is my current JS:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
ev.dataTransfer.setData("div", ev.target.id);
var i = 0;
}

function drop(ev,el) { 
var newId = 'newaccount';

ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("div");
var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
nodeCopy.id = newId+i; 
nodeCopy.class = 'newaccount';
ev.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i was going through the same problem what i did was that when a div was dropped i stored its id in a variable and compare it with the above lying elements like

```
$('#'+idvariable).prevAll.each(function(){
$upperid= $(this).attr("id");
if(idvariable == upperid){
//do something
}
});
```

it didn't completely solved my problem, due to other code, but it might work in your code.